# multiple model values in non model controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically I am trying that creating dashboard that contains wizard. I have bunch of models and there values, and now I want to access some values(columns of the model table)from all model.

I need a help that which wizard(for creating next.., next button of the page form) is best way to solve this problem and how to access multiple model values in none model single or multiple controller.

Any help must appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a controller you just have to call the name of the models like youy . 
For example, if you want wizards model, you just have to do `Wizard.method_you_want`

If you want all wizards: `wizards = Wizard.all`
If you want a specific wizard: `wizard = Wizard.find(wizard_id)`

Then, for example, to get the value you want from the model: `wizard.id`, `wizard.super_power`, `wizard.value`.

For other models you just have to do the same.

Comment: currently I am using wicked wizard. is it support for accessing multiple model values and display in single page ?

Comment: Yes, but maybe you want to do that in the controller

Comment: Yes in single controller only. I am able to access that in each single model value in single controller. but how can we  retrieve data from two different model in single controller?

Comment: You do something like  `@wizard  = Wizard.find(id)` and `@model = Model.find(model_id)`, then you just have to get the values from the models 
`@wizard.name`.